# remove element from array without reindex

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have this code to add elements to an array and remove one element.

```js
var test = []

test.push({
    bezeichnung: "test_1"
});
test.push({
    bezeichnung: "test_2"
});
test.push({
    bezeichnung: "test_3"
});



// Element aus Array entfernen
test.splice(1, 1);
console.log(test)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

My console log:

```
Array [ {…}, {…} ]

0: Object { bezeichnung: "test_1" }
1: Object { bezeichnung: "test_2" } // was removed
1: Object { bezeichnung: "test_3" }
```

But how can I realize, that the "key" from test 3 will not changed? It should be 2 instead 1. Is there a way?

Comment: Why would you need to change this? the index of the array will tell you

Comment: in my console: `0: Object { bezeichnung: "test_1" }
​1: Object { bezeichnung: "test_3" }`

Comment: What is expected output? `0: Object { bezeichnung: "test_1" } ​1: Object { bezeichnung: "test_renamed_to_2" }` ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the keyword `delete` instead of `splice`

```js
var test = []

test.push({
    bezeichnung: "test_1"
});
test.push({
    bezeichnung: "test_2"
});
test.push({
    bezeichnung: "test_3"
});



// Element aus Array entfernen
delete test[1];
console.log(test)
```

Comment: Why would an undefined be an improvement?

Comment: @mplungjan It’s not undefined. The index itself no longer exists. The Stack Snippet console doesn’t display this correctly. A direct test is [`Object.hasOwn`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwn)`(test, 1) === false`.

Comment: not an improvement...but what OP asked all in all  ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: `console.log(JSON.stringify(test))` shows `[{"bezeichnung":"test_1"},null,{"bezeichnung":"test_3"}]`